# jQuery script function seems not to be loaded

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am about to use jQuery in my wordpress installation. Thus I have used the appropriate wp_`enqueue_script` function to load this and additionally the jQZoom-script.

As a result, the following lines can be found in my header in this order

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jQZoom_style-css'  href='http://mysite.de/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/jqzoom_ev-2.3/css/jquery.jqzoom.css?ver=2.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js?ver=1.9.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mysite.de/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/jqzoom_ev-2.3/js/jquery.jqzoom-core.js?ver=2.3'></script>
```

The according files do all exist.
However, my little test script shortly above the footer (i.e. in the body) does not work (neither does the demanded function):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (jQuery()) { 
  alert('3ja');
} else {
  alert('3nein');
}

if ($()) { 
  alert('2ja');
} else {
  alert('2nein');
}

if (jqzoom()) { 
  alert('1ja');
} else {
  alert('1nein');
}
</script>
```

I get the `3ja` and the `2ja`, but neither a `1ja` nor a `1nein`

Also I have the following in my body, which is supposed to show the zoom function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.zoomTarget').jqzoom();  
});
</script>
<a href="http://mysite.de/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/triumph_big3.jpg" title="triumph_big3" class="zoomTarget">
  <img src="http://mysite.de/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/triumph_small3.jpg" title="triumph_small3" />
</a>
```

The Chrome js console shows the following errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jqzoom is not defined mysite.de:131
(anonymous function) mysite.de:131
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqzoom' mysite.de:111
(anonymous function) helga-matzke.de:111
c jquery.min.js:3
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:3
b.extend.ready jquery.min.js:3
H jquery.min.js:3
```

Thank you!

Comment: error in jqzoom() call. JQuery is loaded, not sure about second api. What error you are getting?

Comment: You usually attach a widget to an object like so $('div.zoom-area').jqzoom();

Comment: I get errors

    Uncaught ReferenceError: jqzoom is not defined mysite.de:131
    (anonymous function) mysite.de:131
    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqzoom'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the migrate js too for 1.9.1

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The version was the problem, thank you! However, the migrate script did not solve the problem, I had to downgrade to 1.6.4